# how to pass a response to a react-native RNPickerSelect funtional components

Tags: react-native

ok this is a very simple action that i want to do i just want to fill a RNPickerSelect with the data that i recibe from a http request , the thing is i am learning how to use react-native and i am little confused. This is the code i have :

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import RNPickerSelect from 'react-native-picker-select';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';

    const getData = () => {
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('GET','http://3.86.214.41/api/v1/web/activities');
      xhr.responseType = 'json'
      xhr.onload = () => {
          const data = xhr.response
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            alert(data[i].id + data[i].name);
          }
      }
      xhr.send();
    }
    
    const Actividad = () => {
      const [activityId,setActivityId] = useState('');
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>Selecciona Actividad</Text>
          <RNPickerSelect
            onValueChange={activityId => setActivityId(activityId)}
            items={
               [ {label: 'actividad', value: '1'}]
            }
          />
          <Button onPress={getData} title="Get Activities" />
        </View>
      );
    };
    
    export default Actividad;
```

you can see the response i iterate just for make sure the data is there , so i want to make the list of items with that data.

from the getData funtion to the items prop inside the RNPickerSelect component hope i am clear enough so please if someone can help me i will vote your answer for thank you so much. sorry if this is to dump question but i can't find a clear and easy undertandable answer yet thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add an extra state to your component,

```
  const [items,setItems] = useState([ {label: 'actividad', value: '1'}]);
```

Then pass this state to your RNPickerSelect:

```
 <RNPickerSelect
    onValueChange={activityId => setActivityId(activityId)}
    items={items}
 />
```

the rest is just change this items state.
we can create another function lets call it onEndGetData end this will receive your endpoint data and update items state

```
const onEndGetData = (payload) => {
    setItems(payload.map((item) => ({ label: item.name, value: item.id })));
};
```

And now just pass this function to getData function so you can set state according

```
<Button onPress={() => getData(onEndGetData)} title="Get Activities" />
```

so in your getData you can use it once you have the response:

```
const getData = (onEndGetData) => {
    ...
    xhr.onload = () => {
              onEndGetData(xhr.response);
          }
```

Comment: Thank you so much this work if i put all together like this :``

Comment: i corrected i typo, did you find this useful or are you having trouble?